# Can I prevent textmate from auto adding semicolons after colons?

Tags: text-editors, textmate

Is there a way to prevent textmate from auto-typing a `;` after every `:` when editing CSS?
I still want it to auto add closing brackets and curly braces. Just not semi-colons.

I've seen the option in the prefs but it will only disable all closing characters.

Comment: Are you editing a CSS, or in which case does this happen? Have you looked into the options?

Comment: yes with css. I've seen the option in the prefs but it will only disable all closing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Other than asking the developers to consider implementing an option for that I don't really see a way in which this could be achieved, there are two ways to handle this by yourself:

1. Consider switching to another editor or even IDE, that's built more towards CSS.
2. Get used to the flow of the automatic generation of `:;` constructs, it was added with a reason.